# How to xshift by 2mm the 5th label "49.2" in my tex code

Tags: pgfplots

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel near ticks,xlabel near ticks,width=0.95\textwidth,height=8cm,xlabel=（年）,ylabel=（亿元）,xmin=2010.5,xmax=2017.5,ymin=0,ymax=130,legend style={font=\footnotesize,at={(0.22,0.4)},anchor=south},/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,xtick=data,every node near coord/.append style={font=\scriptsize, /pgf/number format/precision=1,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},legend cell align=left,minor tick num=3,ytick={20,40,60,80,100,120}
,every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize},every axis x label/.style={at={(0.97,-0.05)},anchor=west,font=\footnotesize},mark size={3},
every axis y label/.style={at={(-0.05,1.05)},anchor=north,font=\footnotesize}]

    \addplot plot[thin,smooth,mark=10-pointed star,nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={swap,font=\footnotesize,anchor=-50,xshift=2mm
}] coordinates {(2011,61)(2012,97.9)(2013,87.5)(2014,91.7)(2015,45.2)(2016,38.6)(2017,120)}
    node[below,font=\footnotesize](dt)at(axis cs:2015.7,80){1-3月投资完成曲线};
    \draw[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,ultra thick,blue]
(dt)edge(axis cs:2014.6,60);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, completing it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best solution but for a plot with only a view data points, putting the line and markers in different plots and adjusting the node positions individually does the job.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
  ylabel near ticks,
  xlabel near ticks,
  width=0.95\textwidth,
  height=8cm,
  xlabel=（年）,
  ylabel=（亿元）,
  xmin=2010.5,
  xmax=2017.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=130,
  legend style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    at={(0.22,0.4)},
    anchor=south},
  /pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
  xtick=data,
  every node near coord/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize, 
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
  legend cell align=left,
  minor tick num=3,
  ytick={20,40,60,80,100,120},
  every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
  every axis x label/.style={
    at={(0.97,-0.05)},
    anchor=west,
    font=\footnotesize},
  mark size={3},
  every axis y label/.style={
    at={(-0.05,1.05)},
    anchor=north,
    font=\footnotesize}
]

\addplot plot[
  thin,
  smooth,
  no markers,
] 
coordinates {
  (2011,61)
  (2012,97.9)
  (2013,87.5)
  (2014,91.7)
  (2015,45.2)
  (2016,38.6)
  (2017,120)
};

\addplot [
  only marks,
  blue,
  mark=10-pointed star,
  nodes near coords,
  every node near coord/.append style={
    swap,
    font=\footnotesize,
    anchor=-90}
]
coordinates {
   (2012,97.9)
   (2013,87.5)
   (2014,91.7)
   (2017,120)
};

\addplot [
  only marks,
  blue,
  mark=10-pointed star,
  nodes near coords,
  every node near coord/.append style={
    swap,
    font=\footnotesize,
    anchor=-180}
]
coordinates {
   (2011,61)
   (2015,45.2)
   (2016,38.6)
}
node [
    below, 
    font=\footnotesize
] 
(dt) at (axis cs:2015.5,80) 
{1-3月投资完成曲线};

\draw [
    ->, 
    >=stealth', 
    shorten >=1pt, 
    ultra thick, 
    blue
] 
(dt) edge (axis cs:2014.64,60);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `visualization depends on`. Add

```
visualization depends on={ifthenelse(\coordindex==4,2mm,0) \as \nncshift}
```

to the `axis` options, and in the `every node near coord` style, add

```
xshift=\nncshift
```

`\coordindex` is, as you may expect, an index for the coordinates, which starts counting at 0. Hence, the fifth coordinate has index 4.

If you'd like to shift the first and sixth label left a bit, you can nest two `ifthenelse` statements, as such:

```
visualization depends on={ifthenelse(\coordindex==4,2mm,ifthenelse(\coordindex==0||\coordindex==5,-2mm,0)) \as \nncshift}
```

---

One other comment: Don't use `\addplot plot[..]`, but just `\addplot [..]`, or `\addplot +[..]`. The `+` indicates that the settings are appended to the default settings. The `plot` keyword is for use with pure TikZ, e.g. `\draw plot ...`

(Code formatting is of course a personal preference, I'd prefer using more lines, hence the reformatting.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  ylabel near ticks,
  xlabel near ticks,
  width=0.95\textwidth,
  height=8cm,
  xlabel=（年）,
  ylabel=（亿元）,
  xmin=2010.5,
  xmax=2017.5,
  ymin=0,
  ymax=130,
  legend style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    at={(0.22,0.4)},
    anchor=south
  },
  /pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
  xtick=data,
  every node near coord/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
    xshift=\nncshift % added
  },
  legend cell align=left,
  minor tick num=3,
  ytick={20,40,60,80,100,120},
  every tick label/.append style={
    font=\footnotesize
  },
  every axis x label/.style={
    at={(0.97,-0.05)},
    anchor=west,
    font=\footnotesize
  },
  mark size={3},
  every axis y label/.style={
    at={(-0.05,1.05)},
    anchor=north,
    font=\footnotesize
  },
  % the following line is added
  visualization depends on={ifthenelse(\coordindex==4,2mm,0) \as \nncshift}
]

  \addplot [
    thin,
    smooth,
    mark=10-pointed star,
    nodes near coords,
] coordinates {(2011,61)(2012,97.9)(2013,87.5)(2014,91.7)(2015,45.2)(2016,38.6)(2017,120)};

  \node[below,font=\footnotesize](dt) at(axis cs:2015.7,80){1-3月投资完成曲线}; 
  \draw[->,>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,ultra thick,blue] (dt) edge(axis cs:2014.6,60);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses  specific anchor for each node label. This is done by adding the anchor information as a new column in the data table. Then by adding `anchor=\alignment,` and `visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment` each label can be nudged to a preferred position. alignment = 0 corresponds to west, alignment = 180 corresponds to east and so on. I don't have the Chinese fonts so a few graph elements are not shown in the image.

This is the result:
[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scatter,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
width=0.95\textwidth,
height=8cm,
xlabel=（年）,
ylabel=（亿元）,
xmin=2010.5,
xmax=2017.5,
ymin=0,
ymax=130,
legend style={
    font=\footnotesize,
    at={(0.22,0.4)},
    anchor=south},
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,
xtick=data,
every node near coord/.append style={
    font=\scriptsize,
    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
legend cell align=left,
minor tick num=3,
ytick={20,40,60,80,100,120},
every tick label/.append style={
    font=\footnotesize},
every axis x label/.style={
    at={(0.97,-0.05)},
    anchor=west,
    font=\footnotesize},
mark size={3},
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={
    swap,
    font=\footnotesize,
    anchor=\alignment, % <- added this
    },
every axis y label/.style={
    at={(-0.05,1.05)},
    anchor=north,
    font=\footnotesize},
visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment % <- added this
]

\addplot [thin,
    smooth,
    mark=10-pointed star,
    ] table {
     x y alignment % <- added alignment settings
    2011 61 90
    2012 97.9 270
    2013 87.5 90
    2014 91.7 225
    2015 45.2 225
    2016 38.6 180
    2017 120 0
    };
\node[below,font=\footnotesize](dt)at(axis cs:2015.7,80){1-3月投资完成曲线};
\draw[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,ultra thick,blue]
(dt)edge(axis cs:2014.6,60);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a good idea, and your code is simple and nice.