# Pgfplots: shift single nodes with nodes near coords

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I use the following code. Is there a way to shift specific nodes of "nodes near coords" without placing every node itself which is a lot of work? The nodes at "Fichte" and "Kiefer" are overlapping with the bar. Thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{gruen.dat} 
Eiche;1.1;0.975
Buche;1.68;1.45
ALH;0.77;0.63
ALN;1.14;1.05
Fichte;2.76;2.98
Tanne;0.18;0.16
Douglasie;0.22;0.18
Kiefer;2.43;2.6
Lärche;0.3;0.29
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{figure} [ht]
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
ylabel={Mio. ha},
width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
ybar, 
bar width=5pt, 
symbolic x coords= 
    {Eiche,Buche,ALH,ALN,Fichte,Tanne,Douglasie,Kiefer,Lärche}, 
xtick=data, 
table/header=false,% <- keine Kopfzeile in der Datentabelle 
legend style={at={(0.2,0.94)},
anchor=north},
xticklabel style={rotate=35},
] 

\addplot [fill=lightgray!30] table [y index=2, col sep=semicolon]  {gruen.dat}; 
\addplot [fill=lightgray!110, nodes near coords] table [y index=1, col     sep=semicolon] {gruen.dat}; 
\legend{BWI 2002, BWI 2012}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Similar questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188756 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384734/how-to-xshift-by-2mm-the-5th-label-49-2-in-my-tex-code/384777#384777

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am really sorry, I used the search but couldnt find a propriate answer, I probably used the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you do not really want to shift individual shifts, but just make sure that the nodes are always above the highest bar. This can be achieved with

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{gruen.dat} 
Eiche;1.1;0.975
Buche;1.68;1.45
ALH;0.77;0.63
ALN;1.14;1.05
Fichte;2.76;2.98
Tanne;0.18;0.16
Douglasie;0.22;0.18
Kiefer;2.43;2.6
Lärche;0.3;0.29
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{figure} [ht]
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
ylabel={Mio. ha},
width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
ybar, 
bar width=5pt, 
symbolic x coords= 
    {Eiche,Buche,ALH,ALN,Fichte,Tanne,Douglasie,Kiefer,Lärche}, 
xtick=data, 
table/header=false,% <- keine Kopfzeile in der Datentabelle 
legend style={at={(0.2,0.94)},
anchor=north},
xticklabel style={rotate=35},
] 

\addplot [fill=lightgray!30] table [y index=2, col sep=semicolon]  {gruen.dat}; 
\addplot [fill=lightgray!110] table [y index=1, col     sep=semicolon] {gruen.dat}; 
\addplot [visualization depends on={\thisrowno{1} \as \myvalue},
  only marks,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\myvalue}},
  nodes near coords style={xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar width},above}] table
   [x index=0,y expr={max(\thisrowno{1},\thisrowno{2})}, col sep=semicolon] {gruen.dat};
\legend{BWI 2002, BWI 2012}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE**: was confused about the rows, thanks to Stefan Pinnow!

Comment: Now you plot the values of the "higher" instead of the "dark gray" bars, i.e. `2.98` instead of `2.76` ...

Comment: (Also you missed to remove the `xshift` stuff in the `nodes near coords style` from [Zarko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/418565/95441) or was that intended to be still present?)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks for your first comment, and as for the second: did you realize that the OP wants to have the value above the dark bar?

Comment: True, you need it because you add it as third `\addplot`, but then it still is wrong. To visualize that change `bar width` e.g. to `15pt`. Correct would be `xshift={(\pgfplotbarwidth + 2pt)/2}` where the `2pt` come from the default value of `bar shift auto` which cannot be accessed by `\pgfkeysvalueof` (even if you add it to the `axis` options -- for whatever reason).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I prefer this one because the figure will be used in a presentation where I got much less horizontal space, so increasing the bar width is no option.  I also prefer the answer because it is more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

you have problem where bare with nodes is lower then bar without it. two solutions:

- make bars wider (that above them is enough place for nodes content)
- redefine positions of nodes above bars

combining bot solutions gives:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{gruen.dat}
Eiche;1.1;0.975
Buche;1.68;1.45
ALH;0.77;0.63
ALN;1.14;1.05
Fichte;2.76;2.98
Tanne;0.18;0.16
Douglasie;0.22;0.18
Kiefer;2.43;2.6
Lärche;0.3;0.29
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ylabel={Mio. ha},
width=\textwidth, height=7cm,
ybar,
bar width=9pt,
symbolic x coords=
    {Eiche,Buche,ALH,ALN,Fichte,Tanne,Douglasie,Kiefer,Lärche},
xtick=data,
table/header=false,% <- keine Kopfzeile in der Datentabelle
legend style={at={(0.2,0.94)},
anchor=north},
xticklabel style={rotate=35},
% for positioning nodes over bars
nodes near coords style={anchor=south west, inner xsep=0pt,
                         xshift=-0.5\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar width},
                         font=\scriptsize},
]

\addplot [fill=lightgray!30] table [y index=2, col sep=semicolon]  {gruen.dat};
\addplot [fill=lightgray!110, nodes near coords] table [y index=1, col     sep=semicolon] {gruen.dat};
\legend{BWI 2002, BWI 2012}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In the original file (beamer presentation) I do not have enough space to increase the bar width. I am sorry that I did not mention that.

Comment: why then in mwe you not use `beamer` document class?

Comment: i adopted my answer to use in beamer. now is see that your question is misleading  ...